# Read a nuget package library version in the target assembly when installed

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, msbuild-task, .net-standard-2.1

How to find the installing package library version in the target assembly?

**Assume that:**

We have `NugetLib` and `ConsumerApp` (which will install NugetLib).

I am using **.targets** file in **NugetLib** named the same, and it will run on the target when installed.

Inside NugetLib.targets file:

```
  <Target Name="Main" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="$(NugetLibVersion)" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

Currently I don't have the correct value of `NugetLibVersion`, and it needs to be set somehow.

Using `$(PackageVersion)"` will not help, cause it doesn't read and provide NugetLib version, it will provide **ConsumerApp** version (the target assembly, which will always be **1.0.0.0**).

If you know a way achieving this including setting some special properties, or even by using text files, or any other own or tricky methods are all welcome and appreciated.

Comment: If  **ConsumerApp** is new sdk project, you can just use this target to get nuget version: `<Target Name="PrintPackageReferences" AfterTargets="Build"><Message Text="Dependencies:%0A    @(PackageReference->'%(Identity), Version: %(Version)', '%0A    ')" Importance="High" /></Target>`

Comment: If you still want a property which could store the related nuget version in nuget package, and then use its value in other main project,you could use a txt file to store that value.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT It is .net standard 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is new sdk style format, you can just add this custom target to get the nuget version:

```
  <Target Name="PrintPackageReferences" AfterTargets="Build">
    
    <Message Text="Dependencies:%0A  @(PackageReference->'%(Identity), Version: %(Version)', '%0A    ')" Importance="High" />

    <CreateProperty Condition="'%(PackageReference.Identity)'=='NugetLib'" Value="%(PackageReference.Version)">
     <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="NugetLibVersion" />
    </CreateProperty>

    <Message Importance="high" Text="$(NugetLibVersion)"></Message>
    
    </Target>
```

Comment: I also answered your comment, please give a short time to try it, +1.